# Why does this bash call from python not work?

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, bitcoin

I am messing around with Bitcoins a bit. When I want to get some info about the local bitcoin install, I simply run `bitcoin getinfo` and I get something like this:

```
{
    "version" : 90100,
    "protocolversion" : 70002,
    "walletversion" : 60000,
    "balance" : 0.00767000,
    "blocks" : 306984,
    "timeoffset" : 0,
    "connections" : 61,
    "proxy" : "",
    "difficulty" : 13462580114.52533913,
    "testnet" : false,
    "keypoololdest" : 1394108331,
    "keypoolsize" : 101,
    "paytxfee" : 0.00000000,
    "errors" : ""
}
```

I now want to do this call from within Python (before anyone points it out; I know there are [Python implementations for Bitcoin](https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib), I just want to learn doing it myself). So I first tried executing a simple `ls` command like this:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen('ls', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.communicate()[0]
print output
```

This works fine, printing out the list of files and folders as expected. So then I did this:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen('bitcoin getinfo', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.communicate()[0]
print output
```

but this gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testCommandLineCommands.py", line 2, in <module>
    process = subprocess.Popen('bitcoin getinfo', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

and here I'm kinda lost. Does anybody know what's wrong here? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
Using the excellent answers below I now made the following function, which might come in handy for others as well. It takes either a string, or an iterable with separate arguments and parses the output if it is json:

```
def doCommandLineCommand(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=isinstance(command, str))
    output = process.communicate()[0]
    try:
        return json.loads(output)
    except ValueError:
        return output
```

Comment: Are you sure your script really sees the "bitcoin" executable? If it is in /usr/bin or equivalent, try giving the full path. `ls` is  ashell command and accessible everywhere, that is why it works.

Comment: I guess you can use [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) now! Do be careful about the [potential security problems with `shell=True`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments)!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either use a sequence in arguments:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['bitcoin', 'getinfo'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

or set the `shell` parameter to `True`:

```
process = subprocess.Popen('bitcoin getinfo', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

You can find more information in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> args is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence of program arguments. Providing a sequence of arguments is generally preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file names). If passing a single string, either shell must be True (see below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed without specifying any arguments.

Comment: The first option you give still gives me an error saying `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 659, in __init__ raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")`, but the second option indeed works! Awesome! Any idea why I get the error with the first option though?

Comment: @kramer65 Are you sure you use `['bitcoin', 'getinfo']` and not `'bitcoin', 'getinfo'`? Brackets are required.

Answer (score 4):

use the following code:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['bitcoin', 'getinfo'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

you are not allowed to use spaces for passing parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but I then get an error saying: `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 659, in __init__   raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")`. Any idea why this also fails?

Comment: @kramer65 I think you have forgotten `[]` for passing `args`

Comment: Absolutely true! Thanks!